# Python: generating and getting urls with a non specified variable

Tags: python, regex, url, python-requests

I created a list of urls based on a pattern using string format. 
Each url looks something like this:

https://www.myurl.com/somestr-0/#X

Where "X" goes from "A" to "Z" (code bellow).

Now I want to iterate through this list and get each url with requests except the "0" in each url should actually be any number that could be one or two digits.

I  used the re module to replace the "0" in my pattern but I don't know how to use the output with requests.

```py
import string
alphabet = [x for x in string.ascii_uppercase]

urls = [f'https://www.myurl.com/somestr-x/#{letter}'for letter in alphabet]

for url in urls :
    url = re.sub('x',r'\\d{1,2}',url)
```

I want to be able to use every url with "any number" instead of the "0" without having to specify what number that would be exactly.

ETA : the "any number" can only be  1 or 2 digits and I want to avoid spamming the website with too many requests by "trying" every possible combination.

Comment: So what combinations do you want to try?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `randrange` from `random`.

```
for url in urls :
    url = re.sub('x', random.randrange(1,9) ,url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `requests`. Supposing you only need a get, you could fetch an url with something like:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
```

You only need to loop through all the urls you have and process the responses. More info at https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    url = re.sub('x',r'\\d{1,3}',url)
```

Is problematic - you need to replace with an actual string, not a regular expression.

Try

```
import random

...the rest of your code


    url = re.sub('x',str(random.randint(100)),url)
```